# How to Get min id for each group, if Linked data in available in multiple columns

Tags: t-sql

we have a scenario where data is matched based on various rules and stored in table, but same combination is not repeated.

new_id ->   match_id

8 ->    3

14 ->   1

33 ->   8

33 ->   14

22 ->   10

Here first 4 records are linked with same family and 5th is separate.
I want to get the min id (either new_id or match_id) and display next to each record, like below:

new_id ->   match_id -> min_id

8 ->    3 ->    1

14 ->   1 ->    1

33 ->   8 ->    1

33 ->   14 ->   1

22 ->   10 ->   10

Comment: How do you know those first four records are in the same family? We need more information such as your rules table structure and sample data.

Comment: first four are same family, cuz they some how link to each other either on new_id or match_id.

Comment: can you give a sample dataset?